# Laravel : Copying Files vs Using Composer

Tags: laravel

I have a question regarding Laravel and Composer.

If I use composer, install laravel, create a project and then create controllers, views, etc via command prompt, will it work on my web server if I simply upload these files?

What I'm trying to ask is, is there is difference between using php artisan, composer, etc to create my files, and just directly copying them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, uploading all the files will work.

## However...

Depending on your composer dependencies, the `vendor/` directory becomes fairly large. You can just upload everything *except* the `vendor/` dir. After uploading, just run `composer install` (assuming you've installed composer on your production server) to install all dependencies. Because you've uploaded the file `composer.lock`, it will install exact the same versions of your dependencies, even if there's an update.

It will save a lot of upload time (depending on your upload speed), but will of course only work when you've SSH access to your server. If you haven't, you can just upload everything, including the `vendor/` dir.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will work if you copy files to your production server.

Answer (score 0):

It will work. They are just files, if you copy them all, why would it not work?

This is a matter of choice and, sometimes, some shared hosting companies doesn't let you get to the command line and execute composer, so the only way is to copy the files via FTP.

But usually running composer in your production server is faster than uploading every single file in the vendor folder to your server.

Answer (score 0):

Besides downloading dependencies, Composer is organizing Laravel internally with namespaces,classes and files. First action that is ever happening before anything else starts in Laravel is this:

```
require __DIR__. "/../bootstrap/autoload.php";
```

Composer is providing base logistics for everything what will happen after.
Laravel is heavily dependent on Composer, not because it can't exist without it, but because it is much easier to organize your project with Composer. So, depending on your server - it is better to update everything remotely with **composer update**, then to copy everything manually.